# Extract/Clip LAS (LiDAR lasd) based on shapefile, using ArcGIS Pro and ArcMap 10.6

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, error-999999, las

I have a few large LAS files which span a big area. I have created an .lasd dataset in ArcGIS Pro and ArcMap 10.6. I want to use a shapefile to define the extent of the LAS file, and extract/filter out the las points that lie within the shapefile.

I have used the Extract LAS tool (tried both ArcGIS Pro and ArcMap 10.6) to do this, but both gave a 999999 error executing function. Have also tried running ArcGIS Pro/ArcMap as admin, etc, but the problem persists.

Does anyone have any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Unless you have a preference for ArcMap, I think you should focus this question on ArcGIS Pro which is a much newer architecture. By focusing on one or other it should be easier to include more details about the data and each step in a workflow that leads to this error.

Comment: I don't have any preference, and I'm willing to accept whichever solution that works. I tried ArcMap as well because ArcGis threw up this error. The functionality, workflow, steps and error messages for both ArcGIS Pro and ArcMap are essentially 100% similar, so unless you know something that ArcGIS pro can do in this instance to solve the problem that ArcMap can't, i don't see any real difference.

Comment: Other potential answerers may not be the same, but I prefer to answer ArcGIS Pro questions nowadays. I still answer ArcMap questions but unless a question is about one or the other and not both then I move onto a more focused question.